# Haskell - Type Errors with IntMap and Data type

Tags: haskell, trie, custom-data-type

We're implementing [Tries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) in Haskell using IntMaps. However, I can't seem to figure IntMaps out.

Here's what I have:

```
charMapLookup :: Char -> IntMap a -> Maybe a
charMapLookup c dict = IntMap.lookup (ord c) dict

charMapInsert :: Char -> a -> IntMap a -> IntMap a
charMapInsert c v dict = IntMap.insert (ord c) v dict

-- Question 1.
data Trie a = TrieOf (Maybe a) (IntMap (Trie a))
    deriving Show

trieLookup :: [Char] -> Trie a -> Maybe a
-- My code
trieLookup [] (TrieOf a t) = a
trieLookup (x:xs) (TrieOf _ t) = trieLookup xs (charMapLookup x t)

trieInsert :: [Char] -> a -> Trie a -> Trie a
trieInsert [] a (TrieOf c t)= TrieOf c t
trieInsert (x:xs) a (TrieOf c t) | isNothing (charMapLookup x t) = trieInsert xs a (charMapInsert x Nothing t)
                                 | trieInsert xs a (charMapLookup x t)
```

This seems to make sense to me, since if there's nothin left in the string, you return the value of the node, else search for the tail of the string in the relevant subtree, and similar for insert However, when I try to run it:

```
 Couldn't match expected type ‘Trie a’
                    with actual type ‘Maybe (Trie a)’
        Relevant bindings include
          t :: IntMap (Trie a)
          trieLookup :: [Char] -> Trie a -> Maybe a 
        In the second argument of ‘trieLookup’, namely
          ‘(charMapLookup x t)’
        In the expression: trieLookup xs (charMapLookup x t)
    Failed, modules loaded: none.   

Couldn't match expected type ‘Trie a’
                with actual type ‘IntMap (Maybe a0)’
    Relevant bindings include
      t :: IntMap (Trie a) 
      c :: Maybe a 
      a :: a 
      trieInsert :: [Char] -> a -> Trie a -> Trie a
    In the third argument of ‘trieInsert’, namely
      ‘(charMapInsert x Nothing t)’
    In the expression: trieInsert xs a (charMapInsert x Nothing t)

Couldn't match type ‘Trie a’ with ‘Maybe a0’
    Expected type: IntMap (Maybe a0)
      Actual type: IntMap (Trie a)
    Relevant bindings include
      t :: IntMap (Trie a) 
      c :: Maybe a 
      a :: a
      trieInsert :: [Char] -> a -> Trie a -> Trie a
    In the third argument of ‘charMapInsert’, namely ‘t’
    In the third argument of ‘trieInsert’, namely
      ‘(charMapInsert x Nothing t)’
```

I'm not sure how to fix the error, I know it says there's a type mismatch, but a the `t` is supposed to be an IntMap of Tries (right?) so I don't know how else to approach this. I've spent an embarrassingly long time trying to figure this out, any code that could fix the problem would be appreciated greatly. Thanks!

Comment: [A nearly identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48739665/2751851) was posted yesterday, and then deleted. Please refrain from doing that -- it is not a nice way of trying to attract attention.

Comment: `charMapLookup` returns a `Maybe`, but you're passing it as second argument of `trieLookup`, which is declared as `Trie`. `Maybe /= Trie`, so type mismatch. Same with the other two errors.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I get that, but I'm not sure how I'd get around it. I tried adding a check for Nothing, but in the otherwise case, how would I get the Trie out?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 2):

Consder the frst error message. It happens in trieLookup, when you take the branch corresponding to the first symbol and continue looking up the rest of the key. The problem is, this branch is not a `Trie a` but rather a `Maybe (Trie a)` (the first character can be unmapped in the root). To continue the lookup, you need to flatmap into that possibly-unfound branch:

```
trieLookup (x:xs) (TrieOf _ t) = (charMapLookup x t) >>= trieLookup xs
```

(or use `case` instead of `>>=`, that would handle both `Nothing` and `Just branch` possible results of `charMapLookup`).

Note that your code contains more errors besides type mistmatches, unlisted in the compiler output:

1. In trieInsert you don't actually store the mapped value:

`trieInsert [] a (Trie c t) = Trie c t`

The RHS of this match is the same original trie, unchanged.

2. The otherwise clause in trieInsert should actually read:

```
trieInsert (x:xs) a (TrieOf c t) | isNothing (charMapLookup x t) = trieInsert xs a (charMapInsert x Nothing t)
                                 | otherwise = trieInsert xs a (charMapLookup x t)
```

Comment: `trieLookup (c:cs) t = fmap (trieLookup cs) (charMapLookup c t)` doesn't work since it tells me it's expecting 'IntMap (Trie a0)' with actual type 'Trie a'. I tried replacing the line with `trieLookup (c:cs) (TrieOf b t) = fmap (trieLookup cs) (charMapLookup c t)`, but that gives me the same error as before

Comment: Sure, the first-character lookup should be done in the IntMap field of the Trie, it's extremely hard to post answers from the Android app, sorry.